# How to change fo:region-body start position (fo:region-body margin-top) dynamically in XSLT 3.0

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop, xslt-3.0

I am trying to work on changing an existing solution with XSLT 3.0 and FOP-2.8; from the pdf snap if you see;

Currently:
See *diagram A;*

[image: Diagram A]

Till now fo:region-before extent and fo:region-body margin-top was always having a fixed length.
Which is nothing but distance between Starting edge of the header and starting edge of the body; was always with in a constant/fixed distance even though the number of rows in *table A* will get decreased only.

Change in requirement :
See ***diagram B;***

[image: Diagram B]

Now as per requirement after keeping a certain vertical length inside the header (example ***length - A***) as soon as number of rows will be rendered my body supposed to be started very next after that.
Which means the space; ***Space left between (A)*** from diagram; that we are getting with existing solution should not be there.
W.R.T number of rows (dynamic based upon xml tag) getting rendered in ***Table B*** keeping ***length A*** in hand; there are two possibilities

```
1. Number of rows can be increased; and vertical length of the table can be greater than the length A; so our body supposed to start immediately after the vertical length of the table.
2. Number of rows can be decreased ; and vertical length of the table can be lesser than the  length A; so our body will going to be start after the vertical length A
```

In order to mitigate that what can be our probable solution/code change ?

Answer (score 0):

You could put all of your content into an `fo:table`, where the repeated content is in the `fo:table-header` instead of in an `fo:static-content`, and the entire current `fo:flow` is in a single `fo:table-cell` that is the content of the single `fo:table-row` in the `fo:table-body`

Alternatively, if every row in the `fo:static-content` is always a single line, then you could calculate the `margin-top` of the `fo:region-body` based on the number of rows in the `fo:region-before`.

Comment: thanks for your response how I can calculated margin-top of the fo:region-body based on the number of rows in the fo:region-before?

Comment: You could get FOP to generate an area tree and work out the height of a row from that.

Comment: that is the problem I am not able to get any solution; may be at run time we can use such functions to get these values and calculate the same....so I might be getting sort of knowledge; to implement the same; any hint or relevant link where I can get an idea of doing same?

Comment: Make a simple document that has, say, a three-row header and another simple document with one more row in the header. Generate the area trees of both and compare them. The extra height of the header table in the second one should be a good approximation of the height to add for each additional row in a header table.